# Hide source of particles

Tags: rendering, particles

I want to hide the particle source (tree), but so that the forest itself is displayed. In 3d viewport this works, but only particles of the pie are displayed on the render. The differences are that the tree is used as a collection, the cake is used as an object. But if I use the tree as an object, then it will be without leaves, despite the fact that the leaves are children. I want to just hide the tree, but render the forest.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way: I turned off the tree collection on the current layer, but created a new layer and there the tree collection is turned on. Still it’s not comfortable, but that’s all I have